# Dart: making sure async info is available when processing happens

Tags: dart

Currently my app does on the spot fetching of data, whenever it is required to be displayed. However, this does present some delays and mobile data usage, so I want to build an initializer class that does a one-time data fetching when the application is started and uses that throughout it's life cycle.

However, `async` calls can return the result out of order and maybe later then when the object is created, resulting in error.

I've already checked up on `async / await` and how to use them to somewhat control the execution flow, but I'm not quite sure if the for cycle will wait for the inner functions to finish before iterating to the next element on the list.

Here is my code (so far):

```
Future fetch() async {
    myLinks = fetchDogList();
  }

Future process() async {
    for (int i = 0; i < myLinks.length; i++) {
      await fetchInfo(myLinks[i]);
      myDogs.add(new Dog(
          name,
          type,
          age,
          color,
          gender,
          description,
          chip,
          neutered,
          humanBehaviour,
          childBehaviour,
          petBehaviour,
          sledgeMaleBehaviour,
          sledgeFemaleBehaviour,
          otherDogBehaviour,
          otherBehaviour,
          jailBreak,
          otherThings,
          foreignAdoption,
          imageLinks));
    }
  }

  Future fetchInfo(String link) {
    name = fetchDogInfo(link, labelFetchName);
    type = fetchDogInfo(link, labelFetchBreed);
    age = fetchDogInfo(link, labelFetchAge);
    color = fetchDogInfo(link, labelFetchColor);
    gender = fetchDogInfo(link, labelFetchGender);
    description = fetchDogDetails(link, labelFetchDescription);
    chip = fetchDogDetails(link, labelFetchChip);
    neutered = fetchDogDetails(link, labelFetchNeutered);
    humanBehaviour = fetchDogDetails(link, labelFetchHumanBehavior);
    childBehaviour = fetchDogDetails(link, labelFetchChildBehavior);
    petBehaviour = fetchDogDetails(link, labelFetchPetBehavior);
    sledgeMaleBehaviour = fetchDogDetails(link, labelFetchSledgeMaleBehavior);
    sledgeFemaleBehaviour =
        fetchDogDetails(link, labelFetchSledgeFemaleBehavior);
    otherDogBehaviour = fetchDogDetails(link, labelFetchOtherDogBehavior);
    otherBehaviour = fetchDogDetails(link, labelFetchOtherDogBehavior);
    jailBreak = fetchDogDetails(link, labelFetchJailbreak);
    otherThings = fetchDogDetails(link, labelFetchOtherThings);
    foreignAdoption = fetchDogDetails(link, labelFetchForeignAdoption);
    imageLinks = fetchDogImageLinks(link);
  }

  Future main() async {
    await fetch();
    await process();
  }
```

If I understood everything correctly, then upon calling the main method the following will happen:

1. fetch() is called, and **only when it finishes**
2. process() is called, starts iterating through the links
3. fetchInfo() receives the nth link, and **only when it finishes**
4. myDogs.add creates a new Dog object, then
5. fetchInfo() receives the n+1th link

and so on, until it reaches the last link in `myLinks`.

Is the above valid, or should I implement further safeguards?

Comment: Looks good to me. If you get the data using HTTP requests running them in parallel might improve performance because while waiting for a response the browser doesn't have anything to do anyway. You might want to limit concurrent requests though to not run into errors when the browser or server limits the number of requests to the same server.

Comment: I'm using the http package to fetch the data, I'm not sure if that opens a browser or not and actually loads the data invisible to the user. But I believe it just retrieves the source of the site, without starting any browser process, by sending a HTTP request acting as a browser, right? (I forgot, this is a flutter application)

Comment: The `http` package supports browser and non-browser (Flutter, console, server) apps. There is no browser involved when run in Flutter and therefore no limit on concurrent connections in Flutter. There still might be one on the server and too high a number of concurrent connections still might cause issues with Flutter.

Comment: You could use https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/http_throttle